# Maatwebsite / laravel give name to Worksheet in export

Tags: excel, laravel, export

I am using Maatwebsite / laravel to export data , I need to rename the Worksheet  ,

below my class :

```
<?php
namespace App\Exports;   

use App\Models\Client;
use App\Models\Item;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadings;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithColumnFormatting;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Style\NumberFormat;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;   

class ItemExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, ShouldAutoSize
{
    protected $rows;    
    use Exportable;    
    public function __construct($client_id , $items , $company_name)
    {
        $this->client_id        = $client_id;       
        $this->items            = $items;      
        $this->company_name     = $company_name;
    }

    public function collection()
    {    
        $i              = 1;
        $client = Client::find($this->client_id);
        $item_new= [];
        foreach($this->items as $item){
            $item_new[] = [$i++,
            $this->company_name,
            $this->item,
            $client->client_name,                            
                       ];
        }

        return collect($item_new);
    }

    
    public function title(): string
    {
        return $this->company_name;
    }

    public function headings(): array
    {
        return [
            '#',
            'Company',
            'item',
            'client',
           
        ];
    }
}
```

but it seems the  public function title(): string  , not working .
i supposed that the title function will work , but seems no
any idea how to give name to Worksheet   ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So close. You just need to implement the `WithTitle` interface.

```php
class ItemExport implements FromCollection, WithHeadings, WithTitle, ShouldAutoSize
```

An example is somewhat buried in the multiple sheets section of the documentation, but I can confirm it works for single sheets too.
https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/exports/multiple-sheets.html#sheet-classes

Answer (score 0):

Laravel-How to create multiple sheet in one excel file using `maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1`.

1st step: I created a multiple excel export file
php artisan make:export MultipleSheetExport
2nd Create a route and controller
In controller I have written this function

```
public function state_summary_export()
{
      return Excel::download(new MultipleSheetExport, 'ADCC Summary.xlsx');
}
```

Note: 'ADCC Summary.xlsx' is my excel file name.
Don’t forget to add this facades in you controller

```
use App\Exports\MultipleSheetExport;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
```

3rd step: Open MultipleSheetExport

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Illuminate\Support\Arr;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMultipleSheets;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithTitle;

class MultipleSheetExport implements WithMultipleSheets
{
  
    public function sheets(): array
    {
    
     $sheets = [
        new StateSummaryExport(),
        new BMRPerformanceExport(),
      ];
  
      return $sheets;  
    }
}
```

4th step: Go to Child StateSummaryExport and add this given line.

```
class StateSummaryExport implements WithTitle
public function title(): string
    {
        return 'State Summary';
    }
```

Note: ‘State Summary’ is your sheet name. Do the same in `BMRPerformanceExport`.
Thank you.